# Why have view counters been modified?

Tags: support, views

I’ve noticed that recently view counters no longer show the exact amount of views over 1.000, like they used to.

Is that to save space or what?

Comment: Any evidence, screen shots or something?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ They're referring to view counts on, say, HNQs. It reads as "5k", for example, instead of "5138". Hovering over the number will show the exact number of views, as Glorfindel's answer says.

Answer (score 8):

They still do; you just need to hover over the label:

[image]

This also works in the question list:

[image]

Once a question gets enough views, a handful of views more or less doesn't really matter. The same principle applies to reputation. It's a little harder to see that 98765 < 123456; it's much easier to see that 99k < 123k.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “hover” over the label. I still can’t see the precise number. No problem.

Comment: Hover: move your mouse to the label and wait a second. (If you're using a tablet or smartphone, you're out of luck ...)

Comment: I see, that’s why it doesn’t work. Good job.

Comment: There is a timer on the hover, so one has to goto the entry then maintain that position or "hover" motionlessly for a second or so.